# How to use states inside helper function in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have simple helper function for API calls, like below

```
const API_GET = async (params) =>
  fetch(params)
  then();
```

And i need to use few states inside of this functional component states are provided by `useContext` hook and its separate file, as global state manager, since `useStates` hook can not be called outside of function and `useEffect` hook, How can i access those states inside the helper function. Plan is to create global notofication & loader handler using hooks.

Thanks.

Comment: This is the time for redux?

Comment: @Sam trying to do it using contexts. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) where you'll have access to hooks. Something like

```js
const useFetch = params => {

    const [result, setResult] = useState();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        doFetch = async () => {
            const res = await fetch(params);
            setResult(res)
        }

        doFetch();

    }, [params])

    return result;

}
```

You can use all your needed hook inside a Custom hook.
In this exemple, be ware that as `params` is set as dependendy array of `useEffect`, any change in `params` will re-trigger the api call